# Sums of trigonometric functions and polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, generating-functions, moment-generating-functions, trigonometric-series

I have to calculate sums of the following forms
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^nP(k)f_m(kx),$$
where $P\in\mathbb{R}[X]$ and $f_m(x)=\sin^m(x)$ or $f_m(x)=\cos^m(x)$.

This problem comes from consideration of some physical systems on which I am working on now.

I am looking for some references and possible methods of computation of these kind of sums. I found many papers about relations between such sums for $P$ being a constant, but no reference for general polynomial. I will be gretaful for any suggestion.